# Token contract security issue

Tags: security, tokens

Accordin to [this article](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard) valid ERC20 token must implements number of methods. Among then these two:

```
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success);
function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success);
```

ERC20 standard does not declares any security advice so, anybody who has contract address, contract ABI and know non-empty address can approve any number of tokens and then - transfer it to any other account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `approve` function allows any address to approve a spender to spend coins **from their own account (msg.sender)**.

The `transferFrom` function only allows any approved spender to spend the approved amount.

This is not a security concern because only the owner of the tokens can approve only their own tokens and only the approved spender can spend.

I suggest looking at a common ERC20 implementation [like the one from Consensys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/StandardToken.sol).